# Infinite recursion when nesting objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

First I should mention I'm rather new to python. I'm trying to put a Container inside a Container, but when I do so, I get infinite number of recursive Containers.

```
class Container(Drawable):

    content = []

    # some more code    

    def append(self, obj):
        print(obj.content)
        self.content.append(obj)
        print(self.content[0].content)
```

Page is similar to Container. I add some elements

```
pa = Page()
ca = Container(color="red")
cb = Container(color="blue")
ca.append(cb)
pa.append(ca)
```

Append, inside container prints the following, which is already incorrect, since both of them should be the same

```
[]
[<src.test.container.Container object at 0x013550D0>]
```

I use this method to print it out

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, page):

        self.print_content(page, 0)


    def print_content(self, parent, depth):
        depth += 1
        for obj in parent.content:

            print((str(depth).rjust(depth, ' ') + " " + str(obj)).rjust(depth, ' '))

            if(depth > 5): # to stop infinite recursion in print
                return
            self.print_content(obj, depth)
```

I get the following, which makes no sense. I never added *ca* inside itself as a content, but it happens when I append it.

```
1 Container [color=red ]
 2 Container [color=blue ]
  3 Container [color=blue ]
   4 Container [color=blue ]
    5 Container [color=blue ]
     6 Container [color=blue ]
```

Any idea why this is happening? If I append two Containers to Page it's fine, but as soon as I nest, it becomes infinite recursion. Also, all Containers with color blue are the same (address). I feel like it's an obvious mistake but I can't figure it out

Comment: You defined `content` as a **class** level attribute. So attempting to modify it for a single instance will modify it for *all* instances, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I did `def __init__(self): self.content = []` for Container and now it works. Thanks! Add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `Container` class, you're defining `content` as a [**class** level attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

That means, that even if multiple instances of `Container` exist, they all share the same mutable `content` list. As soon as you modify that list (whether you do that with `self.content.append()` or `Container.content.append()`), you're changing that list for *all* those objects.

Initialize `content` as an instance attribute in `__init__()` instead:

```
class Container(Drawable):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.content = []
```

*(The `super(Container, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` call is because I don't know what your `Drawable` class looks like. It might also need to have its intitialiser called, and so we're accepting all positional and keyword arguments here, and just pass them on, before initialising `self.content`)*